# Itext7 - html2PDF issue with rendering the ordered list

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, itext7, pdfhtml

Iam using Itext7 HTML2PDF 3.0.5 to convert my html to PDF. In my html I have an ordered List and after converting to HTML, the listis been overalpped by the content of the list.

Before i was using ITEXT XMLWorker, with i don't have this issue but i ahve other issues with tables. To fix them I moved to itext7 htmltopdf.

Could some one please help me with this issue?

Here is my sample code snippet

```java
public static byte[] html2pdf(String htmlString) throws Exception {

        Document pdfDoc = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        try {
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(baos);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
            ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
            HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlString, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
            pdfDocument.close();
            return baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                baos.close();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
```

[sample1-generated pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19UiW.png)
[sample2-generated pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTpzn.png)

[sample1-Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92NK8.png)
[sample2-expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryU0O.png)

Comment: Could you please update your question by providing us with input HTML?

Comment: @PavelChermyanin I don't see any option to upload input html here. How can I upload the file?

Comment: You can add minimal Html and CSS to reproduce this issue as a code block.